# How is replacing an running image in kubernetes carried out?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

How does kubernetes (or docker perhaps) cope with references to images in yaml deployments or daemonsets, etc when a new image is pulled to the machine but for which the old image (same name and tag) is still running?

In this case I'm referring to a deployment or daemonset with PullIfNotPresent.

As I wrote this, I may have asked and answered my own question.

This is how I think it works, but could be wrong, please correct me.

The image IfNotPresent is pulled to the machine when the deployment/daemonset is applied.  Kubernetes starts it running based on the image name:hash it referred to (which is likely just an alias for the overall sha)

When a different and new image is pulled with the same image name:tag as the running deployment/daemonset, this new image comes with a differrent sha.  So, nothing really happens except that docker untags the previous image that held the name:tag of the former images.

Now docker contains two images.  One that is formally name:tag but now is untagged, and a new image with the same name:tag, but on a freshly minted image.

Once the pod referred to by the deployment/daemonset is recreated it will use the newer image version with the new sha.

Are there any missing parts worth noting that I missed or am mistaken about?

Comment: That matches how I'd expect things to work (and how `docker run` works).  Note that this means that your Deployment could be running different versions of the code if Pods are deployed on different nodes with different copies of the image.  It's usually a better practice to use a fixed tag (maybe a date stamp or a source control commit ID) that corresponds to a fixed image to avoid this problem.

Comment: Not really, I think I've asked and answered my own question.  @DavidMaze does bring up a good point about how the image is distributed among nodes and better roll-out.